# constant connection to redis server

Tags: redis

I've noticed that when I run a php script on my redis server (simple set / get) that it will load in under 1 ms.  If I have two servers, a web server and a redis server, it will take a good 15 ms for the web server to connect, set, and get.  Is there a way to make a constant connection between the two servers so I don't need to reconnect every single time the script is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the client library you are using to communicate with redis if it supports/creates a persistent connection or a pool of pre-created connections in order to save initial handshaking for each request.